# Android Button Details

Tags: java, android, button

Why we pass these parameters in `setOnClickListener` method?

Plz explain in details?

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          // Do something in response to button click
     }
});
```

Comment: why is because the API requires those parameters. You can look at the documentation. It explains in details

Comment: Do you know callBack interface implementation concept? Check [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip10.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button.setOnClickListener` it is actually creating an Anonymous Inner Class which implements `OnClickListener.` An anonymous class is defined and instantiated in a single succinct expression using the new operator. It is used for creating simple delegate callback objects. These anonymous inner classes can access the static and instance variables of the enclosing outer class.

For more details, please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699844/android-setonclicklistener-parameter).

Comment: And why we are passing a    view object to onCLick method?

Answer (score 1):

Actually these are not parameters , if you know Java well, you might have heard about `Anonymous Inner Classes`. So you can achieve what exactly you need, just by implementing `onClickListener`.

Pass this as parameter `button.setOnClickListener(this);` in your code and do `Override` the `onClick` method.

Comment: why those are not parameters?

Comment: those are anonymous inner class implementation @blackbelt

Comment: so you can not pass a class as parameter to a method?